# gsub all characters from beginning of multiline string preceeding specified characters

Tags: ruby

I have a large multiline string, which is a script element from an HTML page and I want to extract some data from it.

There's a line that has the data I need:

```
var skuProducts=[{"skuAttr":"200007763:201336100;491:200004763#145cm","skuPropIds":"201336100,200004763","skuVal":{"actSkuBulkCalPrice":"313.64"}}];
```

I only need the part between the first `[` and last `]`.

Comment: Write example of your input and desired output

Comment: It starts with

if(!window.runParams) {
  window.runParams = {};
  }
  window.runParams.minPrice="440.2";
  window.runParams.maxPrice="577.6";

And then I need the javascript results array further on down starting on this line

 var skuProducts=[{ a lot of javascript "name":"value" pairs
 ... 
  }}]

So from that I need to strip off everything following and including ] multiline
What follows after the javascript results array looks like this

var GaData = {
        pageType: "product",
        productIds: "en32959852599",
        totalValue: "US $330.15"
    };

Comment: Add this data to your question

Comment: This doesn't look like Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create your "multiline string" first so we can test this:

```
> page = %(hello\nvar skuProducts=[{"skuAttr":"200007763:201336100;491:200004763#145cm","skuPropIds":"201336100,200004763","skuVal":{"actSkuBulkCalPrice":"313.64"}}];\nworld\n)
```

Ok, now let's extract the data using a regular expression:

```
> skudata = page[/var skuProducts=\[(.+?)\];/, 1]
> puts skudata.inspect
{"skuAttr":"200007763:201336100;491:200004763#145cm", "skuPropIds":"201336100,200004763","skuVal":{"actSkuBulkCalPrice":"313.64"}}
```

Yeah looks about right, we can probably read it in as JSON:

```
> require 'json'
> data = JSON.load(skudata)
> puts data["skyPropIds"]
201336100,200004763
```

It works. Hurray.

Comment: Can you please explain the regex

Comment: The regexp just captures everything between `var skuProducts=[` and `];`.